# Existence of a polygon with specified interior angle measures

Tags: geometry, polygons, plane-geometry

We all know that the sum of the interior angles of a polygon is $180^{\circ} (n-2)$. But is the converse true? Given a sequence of $n$ angle measures whose sum is $180^{\circ} (n-2)$, can it be realized by a polygon?

Let me be more precise.
Let $n \ge 3$ be a positive integer, and let $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ be a sequence of real numbers so that $0 < \alpha_i < 360$ for all $i$, and
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = 180(n - 2).$$

Does there necessarily exist a non-intersecting plane polygon $P_1P_2\ldots P_n$ so that the measure of $\angle P_{i-1} P_i P_{i+1}$ is $\alpha_i$ degrees for all $i$, assuming that $P_0 = P_n$?

Comment: The answer is yes. The challenge may be to find one of the infinite similar possible such polygons.

Comment: It seems obvious, but I don't know how to prove it. Non-convex polygons can be very complicated. Perhaps an induction on the number of sides?

Comment: Interesting approach. Start with 180 and 3 sides.  Try it for 4 and you get more than one solution - I believe you get 3 essential different solutions.

Comment: Did it help? If you are interested in a solution I could try one - but it is not free - you are asked to approve it - so my effort is paid off:) The reason I am stating this is since some individual doe snot have the curtsey